# php keep same query for linked pages

Tags: php, redirect

I have the following situation. Whenever the URL of a current page of my site looks like this: http://thisismysite.net/example.php?no_redirect=true I need all the pages my users visit from there to automatically add the "?no_redirect=true" part at the very end of the URL in order to execute the query but I got no clear idea on how to do it.

For example, on example.php I have the following links to other pages within my site.

-about.php
-contact.php

If you click on those, you are redirected to about.php and contact.php respectively. However, if instead of example.php we have example.php?no_redirect=true on the address bar you should be redirected to about.php?no_redirect=true and contact.php?no_redirect=true respectively.

I tried with a referrer like this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'true') == false) { 
  $_GET['no_redirect']="true";
}
```

it didnt work. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the `no_redirect=true` for?

Comment: I have a mobile version of my site. When you enter my site from a mobile you are automatically redirected to the mobile version but after that you have also the option to see the PC version. The no_redirect means no redirection to the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: I would recommend to save the `no_redirect` variable(true/false) on `$_SESSION` when the user requests the `example.php` page.

Than on other pages, check the `$_SESSION` variable instead of the `$_GET` 
variable.

---

Solution 2: You could generate a variable based on the `$_GET` parameter, something like this:

```
$no_redirect_param = "";

if(isset($_GET['no_redirect']) && $_GET['no_redirect'] == "true"){
    $no_redirect_param = "?no_redirect=true";
}
```

and than include this variable at the end of each link:

```
<a href="about.php<?php echo $no_redirect_param; ?>">About</a>
```

Comment: Thank you but that wouldnt work for me because I have many links on my site and that solution would imply to define a variable for each one of them which is out of the question. Maybe a .htaccess will work better?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more generic solution. No, you can't really change .htaccess just because of this get parameter. I'm don't think there is any other solution to pass the get parameter(there shouldn't be).

Comment: I saw you edited your answer but its pretty much the same problem. I would need to add a variable for every link on page.

Comment: No, you don't add a variable for every link. You just concatenate the same variable to each link. How many links do you have?

Comment: Believe me, many and I am to add new ones from time to time so its out of the question.

Comment: Let's say you find a way to include this variable on every link on your `example.php`. What are you going to do about the external links?

Comment: I have no external links but even if i had, i think we can take care of those too more easily.

Comment: Why isn't the first solution that I proposed working for you(using $_SESSION)? Another solution is if you treat your whole page as a form and every link as a submission of the form than you could include the `no_redirect` as a hidden field.

Comment: Waht about a header redirection instead?

Comment: Header is for setting parameters on HTTP_RESPONSE, GET parameters are on HTTP_REQUEST. What's wrong with using $_SESSION?

Comment: Thats okay, the problem is as i said, i would need to add it to every link manually.

Comment: I have a mobile version of my site. When you enter my site from a mobile you are automatically redirected to the mobile version but after that you have also the option to see the PC version. The no_redirect means no redirection to the mobile version.

Comment: No, you should read my answer again. I'm not saying to "add it to every link manually". But, currently you are using somewhere $_GET['no_redirect'] where you don't redirect the user to the mobile version. You would only change that $_GET to $_SESSION. So, learn about [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and understand my answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But you said "and than include this variable at the end of each link" which implies I have to modify every link I have one by one.

Comment: No man, thats another solution. They are separated with a line and the second one starts with "Other than that".